# Lambda expression to compare two lists and find differences and the ones with missing result data

Tags: java, list, lambda, compare

I have two lists where the first one is data I have collected and the other is data from the DB.

If I would like to compare these two lists and find all rows from database (existingTips) that are missing result but where I have got this information in the newTips list I would be able to do something similar to this.

```
List<Tips> tipsToUpdate = new ArrayList<>();

newTips.forEach(nt ->
        existingTips.stream()
                      .filter(et -> nt.getTipKey.equals(et.getTipKey()) && 
                              nt.getResult != null && et.getResult == null))
                      .forEach(tipsToUpdate::add));
```

But if I would like to find all objects from newTips lists that have a "tipKey" that does not exist in existingTips list. I want to save these to a tipsToSave list.
How would I write this kind of lambda expression?

Is it possible to make these two expressions in the same expression or is it better to keep them separate?

Edit: After Alexanders solution I found that I had been thinking a little bit wrong.

When I save to DB I create an @ID. So in the existingTips I have an ID but not in the newTips. So I would actually need to get the getId from existingTip since I do not have it in the newTips. The result could actually just consist of getId from existingTip and the getResult from newTips.

```
List<Tips> result = 
        newTips.stream()
               .filter(nt -> existingTipByKey.containsKey(nt.getTipKey())
               .filter(nt -> nt.getResult != null && 
                             existingTipByKey.get(nt.getTipKey()).getResult == null)
               .collect(new UpdateDTO(existingTipByKey.get(nt.getTipKey()).getId, nt.getResult());
```

I understand that I can´t do as above with collect to new UpdateDTO.

Where UpdateDTO concist of long id and String result. Do you have any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to get two lists at the end. The first one being `tipsToUpdate` and the second one being `tipsToSave`. This can be done using `Collectors.partitioningBy`. Here is an example

```
    Set<String> existingTipKeys = existingTips.stream()
            .filter(t -> t.getResult() == null)
            .map(Tips::getTipKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Use a Set or Map to check the keys. As mentioned in another answer it will increase performance.
    Map<Boolean, List<Tips>> tips = newTips.stream()
            .filter(t -> t.getResult() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(t -> existingTipKeys.contains(t.getTipKey())));
    List<Tips> tipsToUpdate = tips.get(true);
    List<Tips> tipsToSave = tips.get(false);
```

Comment: I found out that I have been thinking a little bit wrong. When I save to DB I create an @ID. So in the existingTips I have an ID but not in the newTips. So I would actually need to get the getId from existingTip since I do not have it in the newTips. The result could actually just consist of getId from existingTip and the getResult from newTips.

see edit update of my post. Do you have any suggesstion?

Comment: How do you know that there is an existing tip that should be updated with the result from the new one? After all you can not compare the tip key then

Comment: How do I know? The place were I get the data from those not have any id on each tip so I have an @Id that is autoincremented and then I have another field that I have made out of other fields which is my tipkey that I can use to compare new fetches and the ones already saved. Basically if the tip already exist I would only like to update with the result if I have got the result in my new fetch that is why I want to get the id from the existingTip. But I could also use the TipKey of course to solve my problem. But would be interesting to know how to solve in with Id and result.

Comment: Do you even need the distinction between saving and updating? Because to me it looks like you are using JPA. JPA should automatically update when the object already has an id assigned and otherwise generate a new id and persist the entity in the database.